# How to prevent etckeeper from saving cups/subscriptions.conf.0

Tags: bazaar

Anacron sends me this message daily:

```
/etc/cron.daily/etckeeper:
Committing to: /etc/
modified cups/subscriptions.conf.O
Committed revision 384.
```

I have added this file to /etc/.bzrignore:

```
...
# end section managed by etckeeper
subscriptions.conf
subscriptions.conf.O
cups/subscriptions.conf
cups/subscriptions.conf.O
```

but etckeeper still keeps saving it. How do I prevent this?

Ubuntu 10.04.4, up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `cups/subscriptions.conf.O` is added to version control. So even though you marked it ignored, changes will be tracked. If this is indeed the case, you can remove it from version control using this command:

```
bzr rm --keep cups/subscriptions.conf.O
```

This will not delete the file, it will keep it in the filesystem as it is, but remove it from version control, so that future changes won't be tracked.